# Odoo search_default_product_id by passing string inside context

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have a wizard that let the users to open a tree of recors with field `product_id`.

This model view has a searchview with field `product_id`, like that:

```
<record id="view_purchase_product_control_panel_line_search" model="ir.ui.view" >
     <field name="name">view.purchase.product.control.panel.line.search</field>
     <field name="model">purchase.product.control.panel.line</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <search>
             <field name="product_id"/>
             <field name="product_name" string="Nome Prodotto"/>
             <field name="numerical_code"/>
         </search>
     </field>
</record>
```

From the Wizard i let the user to input a product name so i can open the tree view with Products filter set with the given string.
Like that:

```
def method(self):
   # other stuffs
   return {
    'name': view_name,
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form,tree',
    'res_model': 'purchase.product.control.panel.line',
    'search_view_id': search_id,
    'domain': [('id', 'in', line_ids)],
    'context': ctx,
    'view_id': False,
    'views': [(tree_id, 'tree'), (form_id, 'form')],
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
}
```

Where ctx is set by this method:

```
@api.multi
def get_product_tree_context_searches(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    ctx = dict()
    if self.name:
        ctx['search_default_product_id'] = self.name
    if self.from_numerical_code:
        ctx['search_default_numerical_code'] = self.from_numerical_code

    return ctx
```

The problem came up when i type the string name of product in try to launch the tree view.
The log say that can pass a string to `product_id` searchview field.
But if i use the Odoo searchview i can type a product name and the search work perfectly.

At this point i make a related field `product_id.name` so i can search the products by this field (present in the searchview)

Is there some way to passing string with `ctx['search_default_product_id'] = self.name`?
Or the only way is to make a related, string field as i made?